# std:atomic initialized with reference creates copy of underlying variable?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, std, stdatomic

Let's consider next snippet:

```
int val=5;
int& ref=val;
std::atomic<int> atomicref(ref);

++atomicref;
std::cout<< "atomic ref="<<atomicref.load()<<" original ref="<<ref<<" original val="<<val;
```

When I compile it under Mac OS X, XCode 8.3.3, c++11 I receive output like this:

```
atomic ref=6 original ref=5 original val=5
```

The line:

`std::atomic<int> atomicref(ref);`

of course looks suspicious since the type under *atomic* is not the same as in variable's declaration - it is reference.

I wonder why the values do not match; is it correct to say that *atomicref* actually creates a copy of *val* ?

Comment: There is no [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) that takes a reference. Also, an atomic reference to a non-atomic object would be worse than useless.

Comment: @molbdnilo: true if you aren't careful how you use it, but `std::atomic_ref` does exist in C++20; see Alex's answer on this question.  The use-case is for example being more efficient in some serial part of your code when no other threads are running.

Answer (score 6):

> std:atomic with reference type creates copy of underlying variable?

There is no "atomic with reference type" in your code. You merely use a reference to initialize the `atomic<int>` which holds an `int` value.

It is not specific to `std::atomic` and similar to

```
int x = 42;
int& x_ref = x;

int copy_of_x = x_ref;
```

`copy_of_x` is a copy of `x` not a reference.

Answer (score 3):

`atomic_ref` class implements atomic references in C++20.
Though according to the standard, you cannot access underlying type during the lifetime of `atomic_ref` by any means, except by other similar `atomic_ref`.

So this should work:

```
alignas(std::atomic_ref<int>::required_alignment) int val=5;
int& ref=val;
{
   std::atomic_ref<int> atomicref(val);

   ++atomicref;
   std::cout<< "atomic ref="<<atomicref.load();

}
std::cout<< " original ref="<<ref<<" original val="<<val;
```

But normally you should just use `std::atomic` instead, and don't access the underlying value.

Comment: Atomic ref can be used when data is supplied externally, and/or you only want atomic access in some window.  It is tricky to get right even then.

Comment: using `int& ref` to initialize `atomicref` is perhaps a little misleading (because it somehow supports OPs misunderstanding). Why not `std::atomic_ref<int> atomicref(val);` ?